# dplyr conditional mutate based on data type

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I want to convert the date only if it's in text format, else not. I need this as sometimes I get the data in date format; sometimes in text format. Here is my toy data.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

toy_df <- tibble(date = seq(as.Date("2021/1/1"), as.Date("2021/1/5"), "days")) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.character(date))
```

When I tried this, it doesn't work.

```
toy_df %>% mutate(date = if_else(is.Date(date), date, ymd(date)))
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: have not tried repeating your code yet, but MAY BE the deal is that you are using ```if_else``` instead of ```ifelse```?

Comment: yeah, looks like that was the problem! I always used to use the if_else.

Answer (score 3):

`is.Date` returns you one value so use `if`/`else` and not vectorized `ifelse`/`if_else` -

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

toy_df %>% mutate(date = if(is.Date(date)) date else ymd(date))

#   date      
#  <date>    
#1 2021-01-01
#2 2021-01-02
#3 2021-01-03
#4 2021-01-04
#5 2021-01-05
```

If your data is in the same format always no need to check for condition.

```
toy_df %>% mutate(date = ymd(date))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! That worked. Just like non-vectorized version of if_else, is there a vectorized version of is.date. I am asking, because I always used to use the if_else.

Comment: Well, a column can have only one class. So it is either a Date or a character. You'll never have mixed value in a column. If you want to use `ifelse` this is a very ugly workaround - `toy_df %>% mutate(date = as.Date(ifelse(rep(is.Date(date), n()), date, ymd(date)), origin = '1970-01-01'))` `if_else` still doesn't work here.